# When exactly cached_property reset?

Tags: python, django, caching

Currently I'm using `@cached_property` for avoiding duplicate access to db.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...

    @cached_property
    def my_opts(self):
        options = Option.objects.filter(...)
        return options
    ...
```

I used this property front template.

It work fine in shell & test. But when I tested in browser, I didn't know exactly when the cached property reset.

Whenever I refresh my browser, the property reset. Then is it useful to use cached property in this scenario? And when exactly the `cached_property` value reset in the aspect of client side?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property) is pretty clear on that:

> The cached result will persist as long as the instance does, so if the instance is passed around and the function subsequently invoked, the cached result will be returned.

Whenever you refresh your browser, you recreate the instance, hence invalidating the cache. If you would like a cache that would persist over multiple requests, you should consider using the [cache framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/).

Comment: Thanks! Then it means it's not a good way to use cached_property in the client side? The instance won't changed till I refresh browser, and when refresh it (or recreate instance), the property is not cached anymore. I might be find other way. (Also I need to read documentation more precisely)

Comment: I'm not sure if you are a bit confused about it but there is nothing client side here. The instance is cached on the server side but only lives while the instance is alive. It has nothing to do with the browser refresh; as it has already been invalidated once the request is finalised (i.e. you see the end result on the browser). As I mentioned, caching your _views_ using the `@cache` decorator which uses Django's cache framework is better suited for your scenario.

Comment: I totally understand. Now I realize it's a bit silly question about client side. I'll try to change into cache decorator. Thanks for detail response!

Comment: @Gulzar Read the docs, it says that you should use `del` to invalidate the cache. I don't know what happens with `deepcopy` but I wouldn't recommend using `deepcopy` with Django ORM instances. If you must, just perform a quick test to see what happens.